# pgfgantt: Labels not properly centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pgfgantt

I am trying to create a Gantt chart, and found this wonderful package pgfgantt. However, my labels do not get properly centered in the boxes. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get the result I want?
(I looked around for an answer, but could not find it. My apologies if I missed it.)

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.75}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid, inline, bar height = 1, bar top shift = 0, x unit = .7cm, y unit chart= .4cm]{17}
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{\ }{0.00000}{1.00000}
\ganttbar{1}{1.00000}{2.00000}
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{\ }{2.00000}{3.00000}
\ganttbar{4}{3.00000}{8.00000}
\\
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{\ }{0.00000}{1.00000}
\ganttbar{2}{1.00000}{3.00000}
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{\ }{3.00000}{4.00000}
\ganttbar{5}{4.00000}{15.00000}
\\
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{\ }{0.00000}{1.00000}
\ganttbar{3}{1.00000}{4.00000}
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{\ }{4.00000}{5.00000}
\ganttbar{6}{5.00000}{17.00000}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

I cannot post the resulting pdf, because I'm a new user, but maybe you can still see it here

[image]

Comment: Would the option `bar label inline anchor/.style=left` satisfy you? You should use it as `\ganttbar[bar label inline anchor/.style=left]{1}{1.00000}{2.00000}`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would really like the labels to be centered, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alignment is correctly centered, but the ganttbars that you create are overlapping. The numbers in the second and third argument of `\ganttbar` represent a kind of slot value and are not (x)-coordinates. See the following corrected MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.75}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid, inline, bar height = 1, bar top shift = 0, x unit = .7cm, y unit chart= .4cm]{17}
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{}{1}{1} % starts in slot 1, ends in slot 1, width=1 slot
\ganttbar{1}{2}{3}                        % starts in slot 2, ends in slot 3, width=2 slots
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{}{4}{4} % starts in slot 4, ends in slot 4, width=1 slot
\ganttbar{3}{5}{8.00000}                  % starts in slot 5, ends in slot 8, width=4 slots
 \ganttnewline
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{}{1}{1}
\ganttbar{2}{2}{3}
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{}{4}{4}
\ganttbar{5}{5}{15}
 \ganttnewline
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{}{1}{1}
\ganttbar{3}{2}{4}
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=grey}]{}{5}{5}
\ganttbar{6}{6}{17}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image: ganttbar example]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a feeling I was just doing something wrong, but I could not figure out what!

Comment: Wolfgang Skala (the author of pgfgantt) replied to my question by email as well today. He pointed out the `time slot modifier` optional argument of the `ganttchart` environment. Setting this argument to 0 will treat the numbers as x-coordinates.